# Applets are not running after installing Java for OS X 2012-004

Tags: java, macos, applet

I updated my mac mini with latest OS X updates and the Java for OS X 2012-004 got installed .
now i am not able to run any applets in my application .
I have enabled the applet plugin and all settings looks fine .
I found out that the applet code needs to be fixed to work with the new update released by apple.
Can any one help me with what needs to be fixed in the applet code ?

thanks
raj

Comment: This is off-topic for SO - should be on SuperUser.

Comment: Pleas update your question to include OS version number and Java Preferences settings.

Answer (score 0):

*Doesn't work* in my application is terribly vague.

- What application?
- Is it just a WebView?
- In what way does it not work?
- Does it not launch?
- Do other applets launch? (e.g. http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/)
- Do you get the inactive plugin error? If the embed tag is too small then it's most likely that you can't see it
- After the install of the update, it disables java *again*, and then auto-disables it every ?30 days
- Did you try enabling the java console (will probably require relaunching the browser/application)?

...